# I missed some homestead missions. Can I go back and pick them up?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

I didn't know that the homestead missions in Assassin's Creed were limited to a specific sequence, so I skipped a few thinking I could just do them later on.  Unfortunately, I'm now in sequence 7 and I've missed recruiting some people.

Is there a way to go back and pick up those missions?  I tried replaying a mission, but the replay ended as soon as the mission did.

I'm on the playstation version, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was wondering the same thing back when I realized I missed a lot of missions. You can still go back and complete the missions--it's not one of those "you miss it, you lose it" type of thing.

However, you should be aware that some missions have prerequisites. Some of them require a certain season, whereas some require you to have certain people on your Homestead. IGN has a handy guide for them here:
http://www.ign.com/wikis/assassins-creed-3/Homestead_Missions

Comment: Yeah, it looks like I was able to go back and recruit the farmers that I had missed, and that opened up a whole chain of them.  They just didn't show up on my map until I was in the frontier.  I was following the IGN/Gamespot guides earlier, but they implied that missions could only be done in the listed sequence.

Comment: Glad you were able to do so; don't let the listed sequence thing fool you. The map icons do seem to be glitchy at times though.